# How to group array of object by month with new key using loadash library group by method?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects such as:

```
[{
  "year": "2020",
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "activity",
      "fulldate": "2020-02-19T15:53:47.882Z",
      "title": "Prediction 9000",
      "description": "2020 Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum",
      "month": "Feb",
      "year": "2020",
      "rating": "",
      "subtitle": ""
    },
    {
      "type": "activity",
      "fulldate": "2020-02-05T15:53:47.882Z",
      "title": "Prediction 9000",
      "description": "Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum",
      "month": "Feb",
      "year": "2020",
      "rating": "",
      "subtitle": ""
    },
    {
      "type": "activity",
      "fulldate": "2020-01-10T20:53:47.882Z",
      "title": "Prediction 9000",
      "description": "Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum",
      "month": "Jan",
      "year": "2020",
      "rating": "",
      "subtitle": ""
    }
  ]
},
{
  "year": "2021",
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "activity",
      "fulldate": "2021-03-19T14:51:15.300Z",
      "title": "Prediction 9000",
      "description": "2021 Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum",
      "month": "Mar",
      "year": "2021",
      "rating": "",
      "subtitle": ""
    },
    {
      "type": "activity",
      "fulldate": "2021-02-19T14:53:18.627Z",
      "title": "Prediction 9000",
      "description": "2021 Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum",
      "month": "Feb",
      "year": "2021",
      "rating": "",
      "subtitle": ""
    },
    {
      "type": "activity",
      "fulldate": "2021-03-19T14:53:34.270Z",
      "title": "Prediction 9000",
      "description": "Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum",
      "month": "Mar",
      "year": "2021",
      "rating": "",
      "subtitle": ""
    },
    {
      "type": "activity",
      "fulldate": "2021-03-19T15:53:47.882Z",
      "title": "Prediction 9000",
      "description": "Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum",
      "month": "Mar",
      "year": "2021",
      "rating": "",
      "subtitle": ""
    }
  ]
}]
```

I am expecting this Output. I used lodash library _.groupby() but I am getting month key separately.

```
[{
    "year": "2020",
    "data": [
        {
            "label": "Feb 2020",
            "alldata": [
                {
                    "type": "activity",
                    "fulldate": "2020-02-19T15:53:47.882Z",
                    "title": "Prediction 9000",
                    "description": "Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum",
                    "month": "Feb",
                    "year": "2020",
                    "rating": "",
                    "subtitle": ""
                },
                {
                    "type": "activity",
                    "fulldate": "2020-02-05T15:53:47.882Z",
                    "title": "Prediction 9000",
                    "description": "Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum",
                    "month": "Feb",
                    "year": "2020",
                    "rating": "",
                    "subtitle": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Jan 2020",
            "alldata": [
                {
                    "type": "activity",
                    "fulldate": "2020-01-10T20:53:47.882Z",
                    "title": "Prediction 9000",
                    "description": "Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum",
                    "month": "Jan",
                    "year": "2020",
                    "rating": "",
                    "subtitle": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "year": "2021",
    "data": [
        {
            "label": "Mar 2021",
            "alldata": [
                {
                    "type": "activity",
                    "fulldate": "2021-03-19T14:53:34.270Z",
                    "title": "Prediction 9000",
                    "description": "Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum",
                    "month": "Mar",
                    "year": "2021",
                    "rating": "",
                    "subtitle": ""
                },
                {
                    "type": "activity",
                    "fulldate": "2021-03-19T15:53:47.882Z",
                    "title": "Prediction 9000",
                    "description": "Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum",
                    "month": "Mar",
                    "year": "2021",
                    "rating": "",
                    "subtitle": ""
                },
                {
                    "type": "activity",
                    "fulldate": "2021-03-19T14:51:15.300Z",
                    "title": "Prediction 9000",
                    "description": "2021 Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum",
                    "month": "Mar",
                    "year": "2021",
                    "rating": "",
                    "subtitle": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Feb 2021",
            "alldata": [
                {
                    "type": "activity",
                    "fulldate": "2021-02-19T14:53:18.627Z",
                    "title": "Prediction 9000",
                    "description": "2021 Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum",
                    "month": "Feb",
                    "year": "2021",
                    "rating": "",
                    "subtitle": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Let me know how can I achieve this. I don't know how to map the inner object to get the desired result. tell me how we can do this in javascript or typescript using the inbuilt method. ready to use loadash library also.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the grouping by month.

```js
const
    data = [{ year: 2020, data: [{ type: "activity", fulldate: "2020-02-19T15:53:47.882Z", title: "Prediction 9000", description: "2020 Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum", month: "Feb", year: 2020, rating: 0, subtitle: 0 }, { type: "activity", fulldate: "2020-02-05T15:53:47.882Z", title: "Prediction 9000", description: "Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum", month: "Feb", year: 2020, rating: 0, subtitle: 0 }, { type: "activity", fulldate: "2020-01-10T20:53:47.882Z", title: "Prediction 9000", description: "Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum", month: "Jan", year: 2020, rating: 0, subtitle: 0 }] }, { year: 2021, data: [{ type: "activity", fulldate: "2021-03-19T14:51:15.300Z", title: "Prediction 9000", description: "2021 Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum", month: "Mar", year: 2021, rating: 0, subtitle: 0 }, { type: "activity", fulldate: "2021-02-19T14:53:18.627Z", title: "Prediction 9000", description: "2021 Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum", month: "Feb", year: 2021, rating: 0, subtitle: 0 }, { type: "activity", fulldate: "2021-03-19T14:53:34.270Z", title: "Prediction 9000", description: "Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum", month: "Mar", year: 2021, rating: 0, subtitle: 0 }, { type: "activity", fulldate: "2021-03-19T15:53:47.882Z", title: "Prediction 9000", description: "Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum", month: "Mar", year: 2021, rating: 0, subtitle: 0 }] }],
    result = _.map(data, ({ year, data }) => ({
        year, 
        data: _(data)
            .groupBy(({ month, year }) => [month, year].join(' '))
            .map((alldata, label) => ({ label, alldata }))
            .value()
    }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```